# RabbitMQ installation with non root user?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am newbie with RabbitMQ planning to use this in one of our product lines. I read in RabbitMQ documents that only ROOT user can install and setup RabbitMQ. Is this a mandate??

Answer (score 0):

In conventional configurations unix systems only the root user can perform system installations

On the other hand the user's default rabbitmq

```
user: guest
pass: guest
```